# How to get custom header from HTTP response in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, http, angular, laravel-5

I'm trying to access a custom header from the Request in Laravel. The header name is "accessing_from". Listing all the headers in Laravel, gives me only the "standard ones", but the one that I've set isn't present in the list. Checking in the browser network tab I can see that the header gets sent. So I'm wondering how to access it from within Laravel.

I'm using Angular2 to make the request with the default http service.

#### The Laravel's $response->header() dump:

[image]

#### The web inspector's log:

[image]
Thanks to anyone!

Comment: Please show us the dump of your `$request` and a picture of the headers being sent with your Web Inspector.

Comment: @Ohgodwy Updated the question with photos

Comment: HTTP Headers that contain underscore (_) are not transferred to the server if you use Nginx, unless not explicitly set `underscores_in_headers on;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you talking about get parameter or something? If so, use:

```
request()->accessing_from;
```

For header you should use:

```
request()->header('accessing_from');
```

The working solution for this was the answer (the last one) of `daver` here:
[Laravel get request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853604/laravel-get-request-headers)

Comment: no, I'm willing to get the exact header from the request, it's not a parameter

Comment: If `request()->header('accessing_from');` doesn't show anything, you may want to read `daver` answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853604/laravel-get-request-headers).

Comment: Trying to access the header with request()->header('accessing_from') returns a empty array :(

Comment: Need to use `Accessing-From` - updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59427256/372215

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simple php?

```
<?php
// Replace XXXXXX_XXXX with the name of the header you need in UPPERCASE
$headerStringValue = $_SERVER['HTTP_XXXXXX_XXXX'];
```

Full answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/541463/3548658

The docs says:
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_header

```
use Request;
Request::header('accessing_from');
```

Comment: @HRLET, already tried that before, unfortunately none of both methods works.

Answer (score 0):

## getting a custom header in Laravel 5.8.

*this should apply to earlier versions as well.*

If using a header like `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` you may notice that it converts this to `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`.

This, in turn, is converted to lower case version for the `header()` method.

```php
request()->header('x_requested_with');
```

I would suggest using `Accessing-From: admin` which will add the apache header `HTTP_ACCESSING_FROM`. And you will be able to access it via the header function like this...

```php
request()->header('accessing_from');
```